# Server does not see http Header sent by Retrofit

Tags: java, android, http-headers, retrofit2, http-status-code-500

I am making GET request to server with 3 headers using Retrofit,
but receiving response code "500" with error:

> Undefined index: appCode
> /home/c/cb37912/url.com/public_html/roid/core/BaseRoid.php
> 110
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/c/cb37912/url.com/public_html/index.php: 15)

I think Server does not see "appCode" HEADER at all, although I can see from logging Interceptor and Network Interceptor being "appCode" HEADER sent. It Postman everything works. I have tried to make headers dynamic, static and also add them to okhttp interceptor. "appCode" is the only header , that server does not see.

Here's my GET request:

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json",
            "timestamp: 1644455642",
            "appCode: a3b5a686a638c08d2880868501ee9c1f"
    })
    @GET("v1/categories")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCategories();
```

Here's the screenshot of Network Interceptor:

[image]

As you can see from picture appCode Header is sent.
Any tip will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: can we see a screenshot of the headers setup in Postman? and the success?

Comment: We kinna solved the issue. I asked a backender to make a fake API which returns sent HEADERS back. And I realized that server accepts all headers in lowercase, although the header "appCode" contains capital "C". Strangeley, when I made request using httpUrlConnection , server accepted everything as I sent and it worked. Could you please explain why Retrofit turns capital "C" in "appCode" header to lower one?